# Delay a method on a new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, delay

I have 2 methods methodA, methodB. They run on different threads. I want methodB to run with a delay of 100 milliseconds after methodA have started, how do I do that?

the code

```
final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
executor.schedule(() -> highs(), 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
new Thread(() -> highs()).start();
new Thread(() -> deleteRecords()).start();
```

I noticed that despise this, methodB always runs before methodA.

Comment: Where are methodA and B? I see `highs()` and `deleteRecords()`.

Comment: Yeah. sorry for the wrong method names. As it is, ```methodA=deleteRecords, methodB =highs()```

Comment: Is that something you're just experimenting with (then it won't matter), or do you need it in real life? Then the accepted answer has a flaw, it can't guarantee that A will run before B, it just guarantees that B starts with a delay of 100sec after scheduling B. Add more threads, use another machine/processor whatever, and B may overtake A. To be ultimately on the save side you'd need a [semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332765/lock-mutex-semaphore-whats-the-difference/2332868) I think

Comment: Looks like Thread.wait and Thread.notify can guarantee execution of relevant parts of A before B executes, check [this out](https://www.journaldev.com/1037/java-thread-wait-notify-and-notifyall-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having the `ThreadPool` execute one thread instantly and then schedule one 100ms later, you'll be able to get the effect you are looking for (having 1 thread run `methodA` and then another thread run `methodB` 100 milliseconds later). I wrote a small example to test this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
        executor.execute(() -> methodA());
        executor.schedule(() -> methodB(), 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public static void methodA(){
        System.out.println("A: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public static void methodB(){
        System.out.println("B: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

This program results in this output:

```
A: 1575782281388
B: 1575782281492
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks.

Comment: Upvoted for reusing the same executor for all threads. @ken4wards that's almost what you wrote :)

Comment: The approach guarantees to delay thread b but it doesn't guarantee, that whatever thread a is supposed to do before actually will happen before. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857910/how-accurate-is-the-task-scheduling-of-a-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor). I'm afraid one would need this awful semaphore stuff to really coordinate the threads.

Comment: Looks like Thread.wait and Thread.notify can guarantee the sequence, demonstrated e.g. [here](https://www.journaldev.com/1037/java-thread-wait-notify-and-notifyall-example)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to synchronize processing between threads, you can use [`wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait())/[`notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()), but if you're not sure about the order in which those "processings" will take place, I suggest you use a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) instead:

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0); // Initialize an empty Semaphore
new Thread(() -> { // This is thread A processing, that should run first
    methodA(); // Run processing
    sem.release(); // Indicate processing is finished
}).start();

new Thread(() -> { // This is thread B processing, that should run after methodA() has completed
    sem.acquire(); // Blocks until release() is called by thread A
    methodB(); // Run processing
}).start();
```

---

*Original answer*:

You wrote:

```
executor.schedule(() -> highs(), 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

In 100ms  `highs()` will start.

```
new Thread(() -> highs()).start();
```

Another `highs()` starts *right now*.

```
new Thread(() -> deleteRecords()).start();
```

`deleteRecords()` starts *right now*.

So `highs()` will be run twice: once with `new Thread(() -> highs()).start()` and then later with `executor.schedule()`.

Just comment out the `new Thread(() -> highs()).start()` and the first executor schedule will trigger as you expected.

Note that thread execution does not necessarily happen in the order it was called, but it usually is the case though.

Comment: Same problem like with the other answer, the approach doesn't guarantee that a could do what it was supposed to do before b.

Comment: @gurioso: the question was about starting b after a had *started*, not *completed*. Though of course it all sounds like he wants to recreate a kind of sequentiality with threads, which would be plain wrong if that was the case...

Comment: @Matthieu, you truly spoke my mind. I want the methods to run sequentially. MethodA before MethodB

Comment: @ken4ward then why don't you run both methods in sequence: `methodA(); methodB()`? Is using threads a necessity? In that case you'll have to use synchronization with `wait()` and `notify()`.

Comment: @Matthieu, it's wise instructive advise. Could you provide a code snippet for the implementation as pertaining to my scenario?

Comment: *"...after a had started, not completed"* yes, the initial question was phrased in a misleading way. But why would he insist on a delayed start, if no order is guaranteed anyway? Btw not necesesarily completed, just executed half way through to important point x, only then B must start.

Comment: @ken4ward I edited to show a simple synchronization using `Semaphore`. It's a lot cleaner and more efficient than waiting for an arbitrary period of time, as @gurioso noted.